# MSI Installer does not create empty directory

Tags: c#, windows-installer

In MSI Installer setup project. I add one empty directory into File System \ Application Folder\My Directory. I build the project.

For application installation when i  the project.msi  there is no "My Directory" because My Directory is empty.

Is i need to create empty directory through the code? This is limitation of MSI Installer.

Comment: There is a part with info on creating empty directories: http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/01/25/from-msi-to-wix-part-1.aspx

Comment: @cookieMonster : I can't use other tool

Comment: That article @cookieMonster refers to reasonably explains this behavior as by design. So for your question, the answer is yes, you have to create empty directories through code.

Comment: It's not a limitation of Windows Installer. However it may be a limitation of the tool being used to author them; sarooptrivedi isn't clear what tool is being used here.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: I just simple create one empty directory into application Directory. If I put the text file inside the Directory then directory created successfully. but when I add empty Directory into Setup project \ File System on Target Machine (File System)\ Application Folder.
That MSI Installer not create the empty directory into Application installation location.e.g :(c:\Program files\{My Project}\)

Answer (score 0):

I'm use Visual Studio 2015 Windows Installer Template . and I found how to Create Empty Folder .

1. Add All Folder (include Empty Folder) into your Windows Installer Project .
2. Compiler Your Project
3. Open Your Project by Windows Explorer and Open File Name {ProjectName}.vdproj
4. Edit this file , find the empty folder name you want to create , replace 
   "AlwaysCreate" = "11:FALSE" to "AlwaysCreate" = "11:True"

   It's worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

MSI supports the creation of empty folders via its **[CreateFolder table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368053(v=vs.85).aspx)**. Even if the tool you use to compile your MSI doesn't support creating empty folders, you can still edit the table directly using Orca and you should see your empty folder being created properly.